# How to develop the ability to solve problems

Tags: education, math-history

I'm an electrical engineering student currently taking quite a few math courses and enjoying it very much. One thing that I have noted in my education is that it is essentially mimetic. I mean that everything I have been taught so far is about copying past great minds. I don't have any particular issue with this, I understand why all of the mathematical tools I'm learning to use are important and I enjoy it.

What I do wonder though, is how to make the leap from learning by copying solved problems to hopefully one day solving unsolved problems. If I meet a problem later on in the world, and I'm unable to manipulate it in a way to use the current tools I have to solve it, how do I go about developing new mathematical tools? Are there any resources that have proved helpful to individuals here? For example, books that provide a certain viewpoint/philosophy or perhaps heuristics or general methods of grappling with a problem that have proven fruitful, maybe stories about how someone conquered a previously unsolved problem on their own. I don't expect to receive precise answers to this questions, but am interested to hear people's thoughts and opinions.

Comment: While mathoverflow.net tends to be for research mathematicians, there are a few popular past threads on there to this effect that may be of interest to you.

Comment: And see also Lee Lady's essay on the subject - again, from a research mathematician's perspective, but perhaps you can get something from it. http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/how-to.html

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about Lee Lady's website, there's a ton of great material there

Comment: "How to solve it" by George Polya, even if a bit dated, might give you a good perspective. The Art and Craft of Problem Solving by Paul Zeitz is more problem-oriented, but it could give you some ideas too.